# How to make a Clustered PK Nonclustered on production DB?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a clustered PK on what is essentially a log table, which clearly shouldn't be clustered.

When I do:

```
alter table mytable drop constraint pk_mytable
```

It takes an absolute age on a copy of the DB on my machine (5+ mins) so will invariably not work on the production DB without causing timeouts or timing out itself.

Why isn't this an instant operation? What's it doing?

Is there any way to achieve this without taking my site offline?

**Update:** The table has 10s of millions of rows, and several 5? other nonclustered indexes.

Comment: Hi Andrew, a drop constraint should be pretty instant. However you don't tell us the composition of the key or how many rows the table contains. I don't think dropping the constraint will not make SQL re-write the table so I think something else is going on. Do you have other indexes on the table? Can you drop them first and then re-create? I just created a table with 1.7 million rows, it took 5 minutes to create a clustered PK over 2 fields but 0 seconds to drop the constraint and only 4 to drop the index.

Comment: "which clearly shouldn't be clustered" - Why? And the reason it takes so long is it's having to rebuild all of the NC indexes (because it's now a heap, and the leaf-level pages of NC indexes contain different values depending on whether the table is a heap or has a clustered index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustered indexes physically set the order of records on the disk with MS SQL Server. So this will result in a whole heap of IO as it rewrites the whole table.

If you don't specify a clustered index, I believe SQL will create one for you anyway as it uses that to cross-reference indexes without necessarily reading records from the table.

Comment: SQL won't create one for you, you will be left with what is known as a Heap. See http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/heaps-tables-without-primary-key-clustered-index/

Comment: That Nigel knows his stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to do this, but here is the best way:

1. Create a new table with same structure (except without any indexes).
2. Import all data from current table to new table
3. Drop current table
4. Rename new table to old table name
5. Create any non-clustered indexes (If your original table had non-clustered indexes & if you need these)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is some form of lock on the table when you are attempting to drop the primary key, generally speaking its actually a good practice to have a clustered index on each table. This actually speed up some operations such as deletes and updates etc . What is your rationale for wanting to drop this other than the fact your table is a log table ?. Again, generally speaking I would only tend to go for a heap if I the table in question was some form of staging table which required concurrent / large inserts to be fast, I would therefore ask the question, have you got a performance issue which is quantifiable when inserting into the table, another viable reason for wanting to drop the clustered primary key is the cluster key being wrong, i.e. wide, volatile and not monotonically increasing, unless you have a solid state based I/O sub system which is not affected by random I/O in the same way that spinning disk based storage is. Nigels correct in what he says, an exception to this is SQL Azure, this requires ** every ** table to have a clustered index has their HA architecture relies on this.